# A single alpha particle can ionise atoms by ripping off their electrons, though can they only ionise a single atom or a bunch of them?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I was reading through answers on the internet and they basically said that alpha particles rip off two electrons to become a normal Helium atom, my question is can it rip off two SEPARATE electrons from two separate atoms? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If an alpha particle is close enough and stays long enough near an atom then the atom can be excited (the electron(s) within the atom is raised to a higher energy level) and/or ionised (electron(s) are removed completely from the influence of the atom's nucleus).

*. . . . that alpha particles rip off two electrons to become a normal Helium atom, . . . . .*
It is highly unlikely that the same two electrons that an alpha particles removes from an atom are the same two electrons which the alpha captures to form a neutral atom of Helium.
What is more likely is that after interacting with many atoms, ionising them and losing energy in the process the now slow moving, less energetic alpha particles captures two electrons from within the material to form a neutral Helium atom.